# PromiseKit 6: How to create multiple concurrent promises and group their individual results into an array?

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

I'm dealing with a weird API where I receive a list of IDs, and I need to request data on each of those IDs individually. I don't need to chain these requests one after the other, I just want to grab them all at once, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this in a clean way.

I've made the method for getting one ID, it produces a `Promise<DataObject>`. How do I turn my array of IDs, into a collection of promises that will then give me `[DataObject]`

```
func fetchDataObject(_ id: Int64) -> Promise<DataObject> {
    return makeURL("\(id)")
        .then {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: $0)
        }.compactMap { (data, response) -> DataObject in
            // ...
            return try decoder.decode(DataObject.self, from: data)
    }
}

// get the list of IDs and turn them into DataObjects

func fetchNew() -> Promise<[DataObject]> { // desired output
    return makeURL("all_ids").then {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: $0)
        }.compactMap { (data, response) -> [Int64] in
            // ...
            return try decoder.decode([Int64].self, from: data)
        }.then({ (ids) -> [DataObject] in
            // now what???
        })
}
```

I think I should be using `.when` but I can't find a clear choice for which method signature... and how to create an array of promises to pass in.

Comment: Conceptually, you're looking for `all`, but, reading through the [FAQ](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/FAQ.md#where-is-all), PromiseKit calls it `when`, which takes you back the [CookBook](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#when) for an example. This may only allow you to pass in a small number of request (2-3 for example), but I don't use PromiseKit anymore (it was a little buggy when I first tried it) and moved to [Hydra](https://github.com/malcommac/Hydra) instead so I'm only guessing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here’s your answer, but as requested “cleaner“.

```
func fetchObjects() -> Promise<[DataObject]> {
    return firstly {
        makeURL("all_ids")
    }.then {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: $0).validate()
    }.map {
        try decoder.decode([Int64].self, from: $0.data)
    }.thenMap {
        self.fetchDataObject($0)
    }
}
```

The key change is the `thenMap` which applies a promise to each element of a sequence returning a `Promise<[T]>`.

Also using Swift one-line closure syntaxes to remove returns and parameter names where they don’t add much value.

`firstly` to make reading the chain clearer.

Using `validate()` on the `URLSession` promise to reject the chain if the HTTP returns a non-2xx response.

Replacing `compactMap` with `map` since `decode()` doesn’t return an optional.

Comment: Thanks, I had different problem, but couldn't figure out ".thenMap" part. Your answered solved my problem too!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got something that works and I better understand `then` and `when(fulfilled:)` now.

You need to return the `when` in your `then`.

```
func fetchObjects() -> Promise<[DataObject]> {
    return makeURL("all_ids")
        .then {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: $0)
        }.compactMap { (data, response) -> [Int64] in
            // ..
            return try decoder.decode([Int64].self, from: data)
        }.then { (ids) -> Promise<[DataObject]> in
            var requests: [Promise<DataObject>] = []
            for id in ids {
                requests.append(self.fetchDataObject(id))
            }
            return when(fulfilled: requests)
    }
}
```